# HP Pavilion-C: Drive

Tags: hp-pavilion

Can I copy everything from my C: to my D: and delete everything from my C: to free up space and it'll still function normally? (P.S I have not had this desktop for more than a month and my 118GB are already almost gone.)

Comment: You could dd from C to D if D is empty and then delete everything from C.

Comment: @stendarr OP is clearly a new Windows user and you are giving vague Linux Answers as Comments.

Answer (score 1):

Everything? No. Some things? Probably.

A lot of things on C: are crucial to the functioning of the Windows operating system. If your C: drive has 118 GB in use, you probably have a lot of user data on there. Much of that can be moved elsewhere, such as D:. But exactly what can be moved depends on what kind of data it is, and what applications access it. If you can provide more details on what directories are using up that space, we can provide better ideas about what can be relocated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are booting off of the C: then you CANNOT copy everything to D: and then delete the contents of C:.

Even if the copy succeeds, you would not be able to Delete "Everything" from C: partition, as Windows will complain when System files start getting trashed...

If the C: and D: are both partitions on the same drive, you *might* be able to Extend C: if you shrink D:, but we need more information to know if that is even a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't know what is using all of the space.  Install WinDirStat or another graphical disk-usage program, run it as Administrator so that it sees all parts of the drive, and let it run for some time (an hour on my PC).  It will show for you graphically what is using the most space, and you can choose to delete or keep some files.  Do some research about Disk Cleanup to help clean up some unneeded files.  If you are not the only user of the PC, ask the other users about their files before deleting them.

If you do want to move your install to D: , research Clonezilla and other disk cloning software.  I haven't used those for some time, so I won't put in precise steps here.